# Show that the solutions to a second order differential equation is a vector space

Tags: differential

Let p = p(t) and q = q(t) be two continuous given functions in p, q : [0, ∞) → R and consider the second order differential equation defined for t > 0 given by

y''(t) + p(t)y'(t) + q(t)y(t) = 0 (1)

Let S be the set of solutions of (1). Show that S is a vector space.

Solution?
Do i need to show the six properties for a vector space?

Comment: Is (the function) zero a solution? Is the sum of two solutions a solution? Is the product of a solution by a scalar a solution? There you go...

Comment: y(t) = 0 always satisfies the given equation. (0'' + p(t) * 0' + q(t) * 0 = 0) ?

Comment: Since $C([0,\infty),\mathbb{R})$ is a vector space, it is enough to show that solutions form a subspace.  This gives fewer things to check.

Comment: Thank you Micheal Burr :)

Comment: Follow up question, how do I show that the dimension of S as a vector space is two.